# Does flaxseed oil need to be refrigerated?

Tags: storage-method, oil

I bought a bottle of organic flaxseed oil to season some cast iron, and the store keeps it in the refrigerator. Does flaxseed oil need to be refrigerated, or is this just a silly thing that the overpriced organic grocery stores do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flaxseed oil goes rancid quickly, and refrigeration slows down this process. So, yes, you should do as the label says (usually a good idea anyway) and keep it in the fridge.

Comment: The label doesn't say, actually, but it's in the fridge.

Comment: Will the life of flax seed oil be prolonged if it is stored in the freezer?